# How to create a new iso image from an existing iso image?

Tags: iso, playonlinux

I have an ISO image and I want to create an new iso image by taking some of the components in my original iso image.

I would like to know how can i do that in ubuntu.

Is it possible to untar the original iso and tar it again with my selected folders.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Mount the ISO:

   `sudo mount -o loop /path/to/iso /mnt/xxx`
2. Copy the whole lot to a directory (say `~/yyy`), using -p to preserve ownership and permissions for the files:

   `sudo cp -rp /mnt/xxx ~/yyy`
3. Make your changes to the directory of files.
4. Create a new ISO from the directory:

   `mkisofs -o xyz.iso ~/xxx`

Answer (score 0):

You can, you just need to use mkisofs.

Copy your content in a folder ' l'ets say FOO ), change things, and just run mkisofs FOO

You can choose the name of the file with -o, like mkisofs -o foo.iso FOO

Depending on the iso, you may need to add a bootloader, etc, if this to create a bootable cd.

Answer (score 0):

ISO Master is the way to go

You can use it to:

1. Add files to an image
2. Extract files fro an image
3. Delete files from an image

You can install it by

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install isomaster
```

or

From USC

Source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_Master)